# using jquery to append rows from sql, resulting all rows appended in thead first td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was going to use jquery to append rows from sql, but resulting all rows appended in thead first td.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfJRD.jpg)

and the code is

```
<body>
    <table id="table">
    <thead><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td></thead>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sql = "select*from test";
    $.ajax({
        url:"query.php",
        data:{
            sqls:sql
        },
        async:false,
        success:function(data){
            var returned_data = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var i=0;i<returned_data.length;i++){
                var temp_str = "<tr class='row'>";
                temp_str += "<td class='cell'>";
                temp_str += "<input class='cell_vale' type='text' value='";
                temp_str += returned_data[i]['firstcell']+"'>";
                temp_str += "</td>";
                ... the other 5 cells is same ...
                temp_str += "</tr>";
                $("table").append(temp_str);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I tried to use tbody but failed,
also tried to remove thead, 
but after it the table width will not suit to the cells,
if there are many cells in a row, the cells may display in 2 rows but one tr.

Can anyone help me?Thanks

Comment: Can you add data which you got in `data`?

Comment: Umm do you mean add in database?

Comment: no, edit your question add the response you got from ajax call

Comment: also, add your expected output.

Comment: in the image :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest going over the modern approach of data binding for much easier and cleaner implementations of what you're trying to do. Have a look at [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/) or [React](https://reactjs.org/), they will certainly help you big time!

Secondly, try moving your `temp_str` and row appendage outside of the for..loop, like so

```
var returned_data = [
    { firstcell: 'cell1' },
    { firstcell: 'cell2' },
    { firstcell: 'cell3' }
];

var temp_str = "";

for(var i = 0; i < returned_data.length; i++) {
    temp_str += "<tr class='row'>";
    temp_str += "<td class='cell'>";
    temp_str += "<input class='cell_vale' type='text' value='";
    temp_str += returned_data[i]['firstcell'] + "'>";
    temp_str += "</td>";
    temp_str += "</tr>";
}

$("table").append(temp_str);
```

And see if it works for you?

Comment: thanks for your reply, i got from your idea, then i tried to remove the "</tr> then all thing right lol

Comment: No problem. BTW, see my edit above. The previous version would not add the "row" class to the TR, now it will.